# asp.net mvc 6.0 project has a default broken razor intellisense

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a asp.net mvc 6.0 project with VS2015 and asp.net 5.0 beta 8 tools.

From the beginning the razor directive is grayed out (disabled look) and the intellisense does not work at all in any .cshtml file.

How can I fix that?

Comment: If Razor editor colorization is not working. Delete the files under `One Of The Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Web\Razor\v4.0\`, then do a Repair.

Comment: Did...with a computer reboot. Still broken.

Comment: A few things can cause this.First determine if this is related to your current project only or to all projects in visual studio 2015. Do this by creating a new web application in a new solution and see if the intellisense works in the views. Post if it does or not.

Comment: Its in all projects I create. But that doesnt matter anymore as it does not happen in asp.net 5.0 rc1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using taghelpers, make sure in your Views folder you have a file called _ViewImports.cshtml.  In this file, you should have the directive

```
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

Additionally, in your project.json file, make sure you have the following added to the dependencies:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta8",
```

Comment: Both are added in my project.